# Can't get AudioTrack to work properly on Android TV

Tags: android, airplay, audiotrack

I'm writing an Android AirPlay receiver.
I use java-airplay-server from GitHub,
But when I try to stream PCM Byte audio with Android AudioTrack
,Works fine on mobile but doesn't stream properly on Android TV and it's all noise
How to solve

```
private final AirPlayConsumer airPlayConsumer =
        new AirPlayConsumer() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoFormat(VideoStreamInfo videoStreamInfo) {
                videoDecoder = new VideoDecoder(airPlayConfig);
                visibilityCallback.showSurface();
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideo(byte[] packet) {
                if (videoDecoder != null) videoDecoder.addToBuffer(new DataPacket(packet));
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoSrcDisconnect() {
                visibilityCallback.hideSurface();

                if (videoDecoder != null) {
                    videoDecoder.releaseDecoder();
                    videoDecoder = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioFormat(AudioStreamInfo audioStreamInfo) {
                int bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                audio = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        44100, //sample rate
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, //2 channel
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, // 16-bit
                        bufSize,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM );
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){
                        audio.play();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAudio(byte[] bytes) {
                byte[] audioDecoded = new byte[480 * 4];
                FdkAacLib.decodeFrame(bytes, audioDecoded);
                audio.write(audioDecoded,0,480*4);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioSrcDisconnect() {
                audio.stop();
                audio.release();
                audio.flush();
            }
        };
```